# Duplicar coluna de uma tabela para ela mesma alterando somente o ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom dia a todos, estou com uma duvida e não achei nada semelhante que possa me ajudar, preciso criar uma função de copiar e colocar ou seja duplicar tudo o que esta de informação e gera um novo ID mantendo as informações.

Estou fazendo um sistema de listagem e controle de projetos para a empresa na qual eu trabalho, segue tabela na qual preciso que os campos sejam duplicados.

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_projetos` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `empresa` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `nome` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `tipo` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `localidade` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `aceitacao_projeto` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `prazo_projeto` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `mub_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `mub_inicio` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `mub_fim` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `lev_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `lev_inicio` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `lev_fim` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `dig_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `dig_inicio` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `dig_fim` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `cal_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `cal_inicio` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `cal_fim` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `art_trt` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `engenheiro` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_data` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_fim` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `rev_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `rev_data` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_envio_colaborador` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_envio_envio` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_envio_entrega` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `doc_envio_aprovacao` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `protocolo_ei` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `situacao` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `concessionaria` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `observacao` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
      `adicionado` date NOT NULL,
      `modificado` date DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

fazendo alguns teste, cheguei nesta formula que ao testar no bd funciona mas na interpretação do codigo ele não executa corretamente.

```
include('../../class/db_conexao.php');  $id = 0;
$conexao->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tb_projetos WHERE id=$id;") or die($conexao->error); 
$conexao->query("UPDATE tmp SET id=$id+1 WHERE id = $id;") or die($conexao->error); 
$conexao->query("INSERT INTO tb_projetos SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id=$id+1;") or die($conexao->error);
```

Comment: suponha que a tabela tenha só "id, empresa, nome", faria um `insert into tabela (id, empresa, nome) select 1 as novoid, empresa, nome from tabela` simples assim, basta por todos os campos e o where que precisar e claro mudar o valor de "novoid", por exemplo "id + 1000 as novoid"

Comment: oi, tudo bom.
fiz um teste aqui com um exemplo na internet e coloquei direto pelo mysql e funcionou mas tentei interpretar no codigo e ele não gera a copia.

`include('../../class/db_conexao.php');

$id = 0;
$conexao->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tb_projetos WHERE id=$id;") or die($conexao->error);
$conexao->query("UPDATE tmp SET id=$id+1 WHERE id = $id;") or die($conexao->error);
$conexao->query("INSERT INTO tb_projetos SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id=$id+1;") or die($conexao->error);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou usar uma versão simplificada da tabela original para exemplificar a solução. A solução para a tabela final é a mesma, acresentandos os restantes campos.

A vantagem desta abordagem é que não é necessário uma tabela intermédia. Mesmo a solução de usar uma tabela intermédia pode ser feita usando uma tabela temporária - através da sintaxe `WITH` - que tem a vantagem de não a instanciar "fisicamente" na DB.

Vamos à solução que me parece a mais simples:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_projectos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empresa` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(128) NOT NULL
);
```

O resultado pretendido obtêm-se da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO tb_projectos 
SELECT
  max_id.id + src.id,
  src.empresa,
  src.nome,
  src.tipo
FROM tb_projectos src
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) + ABS(MIN(ID)) + 1 AS ID FROM tb_projectos) max_id ON 1 = 1;
```

O novo indice é calculado somando o maior valor do campo `id`, com o módulo do menor existente na tabela à data da inserção e o valor inicialmente atribuído ao campo `id`. A este valor adiciona-se 1 para garantir que não existe colisão mesmo que o indice mais pequeno seja 0.

Uma pergunta: Porque não usar a coluna id como chave auto-incrementada?
Dessa forma, a preocupação do índice único fica entregue à DB e o insert de replicação fica ainda mais simples:

```
INSERT INTO tb_projectos (empresa, nome, tipo)
SELECT empresa, nome, tipo
FROM tb_projectos;
```

A tabela teria de ser definida atribuindo a propriedade `AUTO_INCREMENT` ao campo `id` e promovê-lo a chave primária.

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_projectos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `empresa` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```